# Find out whether the game is fair

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Player A and Player B are flipping a symmetric coin. Player A wins if the combination HHT occurs, while the second players wins in case if HTT. Is this game fair?

The answer is that the first player is more likely to win, by intuitively I cannot understand why.

I guess I need a hint

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

After each occurence of "$\ H\ $" , the first player wins surely, if "$\ H\ $" occurs again, but if "$\ T\ $" occurs , the second player only has a $\ 50-50-$chance.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely not very fair. If I had to calculate the probability to win for each player, would I have to consider only the outcomes starting from an occurrence of H since this is what actually starts the game?

Comment: Whenever "$\ H\ $" occured , the question is : What comes first ? "$\ TT\ $ " or "$\ H\ $" ?. $H$ has the double chance to come, hence the winning chance for the first player is twice the winning chance for the second. Hence , the first player wins with probability $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: If after "$\ H\ $" , "$\ TH\ $" occurs, we have the same situation as after the first occurence of "$\ H\ $"